# Can Git merge --squash preserve commit comments?

Tags: git, git-merge

Is there a way of automatically adding all the commit comments from the squashed `mybranch` commits when doing a

```
git merge --squash mybranch
```

so that the single commit contains a concatenation of all the commit comments from `mybranch`

Comment: You could squash first in the feature branch, concatenate or rearrange the comments by hand during the interactive rebase, and then merge the squashed branch.  How many commits are you planning to squash?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think that's what "git merge --squash" does automatically!  Just do the commit with "git commit --no-edit" and I think that's what you'll get.  I see all the commit messages inside .git/SQUASH_MSG immediately after I run the "git merge --squash" command.  Do you?

Personally, I squash into master, but then force-push the result back to my topic branch.  This way my final commit can be code-reviewed via pull-request.

Live example (try these exact commands, this uses my demo server, and really works):

```
git clone http://vm.bit-booster.com/bitbucket/scm/bb/rebase-example-2.git
cd rebase-example-2
git checkout branch
git reset --hard origin/master
git merge --squash origin/branch
git commit --no-edit

git show
commit 74656c51212526af49382c985419244737141217
Author: G. Sylvie Davies <sylvie@bit-booster.com>
Date:   Mon Dec 26 22:07:50 2016 -0800

    Squashed commit of the following:

    commit 3120cbba4e94e0a81eed2f9ff42e7012cca996bf
    Author: G. Sylvie Davies <sylvie@bit-booster.com>
    Date:   Thu Dec 15 18:24:02 2016 -0800

        b2

    commit ccb522334464879b8f39824031c997b57303475d
    Merge: 6b85efb 026bf0c
    Author: G. Sylvie Davies <sylvie@bit-booster.com>
    Date:   Thu Dec 15 18:13:35 2016 -0800

        m

    commit 6b85efbddbb74d49a096bfc54fd4df15e261b72f
    Author: G. Sylvie Davies <sylvie@bit-booster.com>
    Date:   Thu Dec 15 18:12:51 2016 -0800

        b1
```

At this point I recommend doing a "git push --force-with-lease" to get this squashed commit up to your remote topic branch ready for code-review.

Note:  I do one fancy thing in the example.  I'm actually squashing into origin/master, not local master, and I first do "git checkout branch" and "git reset --hard origin/master".  This keeps my local master unperturbed by this operation, so that whatever I might be working on there is left alone.

I'm on Git 2.7.4.  Maybe older gits behave differently, I don't know.

If you want to do this all in Web UI, and you happen to be using Atlassian Bitbucket Server (the on-premises version), you can install my [Bit-Booster](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.bit-booster.bb/server/overview) paid add-on, and hit the big "Squash" button it puts on pull-requests.  It does the exact same thing, except that only non-merge commit messages are concatenated.

[image]

Comment: I tend not to use `git merge --squash` but just tested this in Git 2.10.1, and it works the same way there.

Comment: `--no-edit` option was what I was looking for.  Unfortunately that option isn't available from the commit within SourceTree so have to do it at the command line.  When done from command line is there no way to edit the concatenated comments before the commit?  Ahh I tried TortoiseGit and its commit concatenates all comments by default and allows them to be edited before committing the result.

I am using Git 2.10.1.windows.1

Comment: Try omitting the "--no-edit".  I'm sure "git commit" will pre-fill your editor with the same contents.  But if you do prefer to use "--no-edit" you can always use "git commit --amend" to adjust the commit message afterwards.

Comment: Also, have you set your git editor?  (e.g., output of this:  git config --global --get core.editor).