# How to show all the individual commits of a feature branch in the merge commit?

Tags: git, github

Right now I am using the following to merge & squash a branch:

1. git checkout master
2. git merge --squash feature-branch
3. git commit
4. git push

This merges the feature branch into master in one single commit, which is almost what I want.

**I can achieve this using a pull request.**

So the merge commit includes a link to the PR, which has a nice list of all the commits I made in that feature branch.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2FZu.png

I would like to include a history like a GitHub pull request does.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f10X.png

My question is, is there a way to achieve this without using a PR? I would like to show a similar layout to the PR's list of commits, but inside the actual merge commit itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a `git merge --squash`, try [as illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41340089/6309), a `git commit --no-edit`

All the commit messages inside `.git/SQUASH_MSG` should then be part of your commit message, which should allow you to keep track of the individual commits that were done before the squash.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command `git commit --no-edit` in your terminal. It should include all of your commit messages in your one, squashed final commit message.