# How to change `git merge --squash` default template on local merge?

Tags: git, github

When I run `git merge --squash test_branch`, it shows:

```
Squashed commit of the following:

commit ac72a4308ba70cc42aace47509a5e
Author: quyen <q@me.com>
Date:   Tue Jun 11 10:23:07 2019 +0500

    Added algorithms for Cosine-similarity

commit 77df2a40e53136c7a2d58fd847372
Author: quyen <q@me.com>
Date:   Tue Jun 11 13:02:14 2019 -0700

    Set stage for similar objects

commit 249cf9392da197573a17c8426c282
Author: quyen <q@me.com>
Date:   Thu Jun 13 16:44:12 2019 -0700

    Fixed a bug in space world automation
```

But what i want:

```
Squashed commit of the following:
 *  Added algorithms for Cosine-similarity
 *  Set stage for similar objects
 *  Fixed a bug in space world automation
```

How I can do? I don't want  to add some details for commit, only name of commit is enough.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3605385/6309 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/53493424/6309 might help

Comment: @VonC How would those help? They explain how to make a squash merge and edit the message, which the OP clearly already knows how to do. The question is how to customize the default template for the message.

Comment: @Wassinger Those apply by specifying the file `.git/SQUASH_MSG` on which you can apply the regex you mention in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am also wondering about the correct solution to this. As a hacky workaround, you can search and replace the following Regex with `*` :

```
\ncommit \w+\nAuthor:.*\nDate:.*\n\n\s+
```